# « être bienvenu » et « être le bienvenu »

Tags: expressions, usage, étymologie

En français, on a l'habitude d'utiliser l'expression « être le bienvenu » plutôt que « être bienvenu » (c'est en tout cas mon cas). Voici un exemple :

> Tu es **le** bienvenu, fais comme chez toi.
>   Tu es bienvenu, fais comme chez toi.

Il me semble que les deux phrases sont correctes. Cependant, d'où vient le « le » de la première phrase ?
Son insertion me parait peu naturelle dans la construction de la phrase, pourtant, je suis certain qu'elle est correcte.

Comment: Il est certain que c'est correct. En fait, je dirais même plus que la première phrase est celle que j'utiliserais. C'est plutôt la deuxième qui sonne faux.

Comment: Pourtant la construction de la 2e phrase est correcte puisque _bienvenu_ est adjectif.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La réponse est dans [*le Littré*](http://littre.reverso.net/dictionnaire-francais/definition/bienvenu)

> **BIENVENU, UE** *[biin-ve-nu, nue] adj.* (de bien-venir) 
>  Qui arrive à point ; que l'on
>   accueille avec satisfaction. C'est un homme qui est bienvenu partout. 
>   Familièrement. Vous ne seriez pas bienvenu à lui dire cela, vous
>   seriez mal accueilli si vous lui disiez cela. 
>  *Substantivement*. Soyez
>   le bienvenu. C'est une fille qui vient de naître ; elle est la
>   bienvenue. 
> ♦ *Toutes vos lettres seront les bienvenues*, SÉV., 279

Les deux premières lignes évoquent une tierce personne dont on apprécie la *venue*, dont on qualifie l'accueil.

Pour la dernière ligne, comme on ne peut pas être une personne et un adjectif à la fois, on est obligé d'insérer le pronom *le* pour y déposer sa qualité, celle d'être accueilli avec satisfaction ; qu'il s'agisse d'une personne, d'un objet ou une entité comme la correspondance.

---

*Précision demandée par commentaire*
Le dernier paragraphe ci-dessus essaie d'exprimer le cheminement que l'esprit parcourt pour arriver à formuler une phrase de manière subjective : ainsi il a intuitivement rassemblé des mots, mais se rend compte qu'ils ne s'emboîtent pas correctement (car ils ne sont pas de la même nature), qu'il est obligé d'ajouter un lien ou du ciment, de déplacer l'aplomb du phrasé sur un mot pivot pour que la construction soit stable et solide, d'où le ***le*** qu'il valorise en le faisant pointer, en le 'raccrochant' à ce qu'il représente.
 
N’ayant rien compris à la révolution grammaticale post soixante-huitarde je suis incapable de mettre des étiquettes objectives et de justifier logiquement la nécessité de ce *le*.

---

N.B. *[la version à télécharger du Littré](http://dictionnaire-le-littre.softonic.fr/)* est plus complète, elle fait référence à l'historique, l'étymologie et peut être un supplément au dictionnaire.

Comment: Pourriez-vous détailler pourquoi *on est obligé d'insérer le pronom **le** pour y déposer sa qualité* ? Prière d'en discourir dans votre réponse, et non pas dans un commentaire, SVP. Je pige que *on ne peut pas être une personne et un adjectif à la fois.*

Comment: Dans « Tu es le bienvenu », « le » n’est pas un pronom. C’est un article, celui du *nom* bienvenu.

Comment: @Édouard On peut aussi l'entendre comme « Tu es l'[homme] bienvenu », *bienvenu* étant ici un adjectif ; adjectif (selon la nomenclature du Littré) que l'on utilise habituellement comme substantif dans « Tu es le bienvenu ». Il semble qu'il y ait ici une ambivalence, deux usages possibles dû à un mot 'adjectif & substantif'.

Comment: Je suppose qu’on peut l’interpréter comme cela, mais la construction me semble vraiment bizarre. J’oublierai de regarder quand j’aurai le temps.

Answer (score 6):

Je fonde cette réponse sur ce [lien](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=268655&page=2&p=9451903#post9451903).  Je garde la réponse en anglais car celle de cl-r est en français. Prière de m'informer si une traduction était nécessaire.

---

Confusion is due to this word's several meanings and usages which are all very closely correlated.

1. The noun that refers to the welcome itself (l'accueil aimable) or to a propitious arrival is feminine: **la bienvenue.**

   Thus we say « Je vous souhaite la bienvenue », regardless of the gender or number of travellers we welcome.
   This feminine noun is also the one we use by ellipsis as a greeting.
   The [Banque de dépannage linguistique confirms](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1469):

   > Dans un sens proche, le nom bienvenue s’emploie aussi dans un souhait. Seul le féminin s’emploie dans cette formule d’accueil.
   >   Exemple :
   >
   > - **Bienvenue** à nos hôtes!
2. The noun that refers to the guest reflects the gender of the guest: **le/la/les bienvenu(e)(s)**.

   - Vous êtes les bienvenues, Mesdames.
   - Soyez le bienvenu ! (to a man) / Soyez la bienvenue ! (to a woman)
   - Vous (m.pl.) êtes toujours les bienvenus chez moi.
3. The adjective reflects the gender of the person or thing that's considered welcome: **bienvenu(e)(s)**.

   - des vacances bienvenues
   - Vous (m.pl.) serez toujours bienvenus chez moi.

Notice how a verb such as « être » lends itself to usage with either the noun form [2] or the adjectival form [3]. This double usage can be confusing and mystifying.

---

Another example:

> "Bonsoir, Monsieur, et vous êtes bienvenu à l'hôtel."

This is an example of case 1. It's an ellipsis that combines two separate greetings, the second of which is itself an ellipsis already. We can expand it as follows:

> Bonsoir, Monsieur ! [Nous vous souhaitons la] Bienvenue, Monsieur !

→

> Bonsoir, Monsieur, et bienvenuE !

Comment: Bien explique.  Pour un anglophone, je dirais que c'est la difference entre "you are the welcome one" (ce qu'on ne dit pas vraiment en anglais, mais ce que est neanmoins correcte) et "you are welcome".  Dans "tu es le bienvenu[e]", "bienvenu[e]" est un nom (a welcome person) et non pas un adjectif. C'est plus courant en francais d'utiliser le premier ("vous etes les bienvenus") que le deuxieme ("vous etes bienvenus").  En anglais le deuxieme est (beaucoup) plus courant.