# « Bienvenue à nos hôtes ! » : sens exact, possessif à utiliser, réponse usuelle ?

Tags: sens, salutations, politesse, possessif

[Ailleurs](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/8543), on traite brièvement de la [bienvenue](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bienvenue/1), en *substantif féminin*, soit l'*arrivée propice*, ou l'*accueil aimable*. On réfère à un exemple à la *Banque de dépannage linguistique* (BDL). Dans le [document](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1469) contenant cet exemple, on discute au préalable du nom au masculin ou au féminin (*soyez le/la bienvenu(e)* ); puis on enchaîne avec ce qui suit :

> Dans un sens proche, le nom *bienvenue* s’emploie aussi dans un
>   souhait. Seul le féminin s’emploie dans cette formule d’accueil.
>
> **Exemple** :
>
> — [**Bienvenue** à nos hôtes!](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bienvenue%20%C3%A0%20nos%20h%C3%B4tes&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbienvenue%20%C3%A0%20nos%20h%C3%B4tes%3B%2Cc0)
>
> On peut remarquer, à partir de ce dernier exemple, qu’en français,
>   contrairement à l’usage anglais, c’est le premier interlocuteur qui
>   emploie le mot *bienvenue*.
>
> [ *Banque de dépannage linguistique* (BDL) - [*bienvenue*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1469) ]

Disons que je suis invité à dîner chez des amis. J'arrive; on se salue. Puis je dis exactement : « *bienvenue à nos hôtes* ! ».

---

1. Quel est le sens de ce que je viens de dire à mes amis, est-ce opportun; un souhait
   de quoi, quelle bienvenue, un sens proche de quoi; dans *soyez le bienvenu(e)*, il s'agit d'un accueil (souvent avec *dans* etc.) ? Est-ce que je réfère à l'accueil qui m'est fait, au fait que j'arrive à point et que j'espère être bien accueilli ?
2. Puis-je utiliser l'adjectif possessif *mes* plutôt que *nos* (*Bienvenue à mes hôtes !*) ?
3. Que répondent usuellement mes hôtes à mon expression de bienvenue ?

Comment: le ngram ne donne pas le contexte. Il n'y a en effet aucun doute que "bienvenue à nos hôtes" s'utilise, mais dans le sens "bienvenue à nos invités" et pas dans le sens que vous lui donnez.

Comment: Personne ne mettra en doute que l'on puisse le dire, il s'agit d'une formule courante, mais le contexte dans lequel on peut le dire sera plus sujet à discussions ! ;)

Comment: Un ngram ne vaut rien dans le cas présent, la formule est correcte en grammaticalement, juste inappropriée dans la bouche des invités et réservée à ceux qui recoivent. La subtilité vient du fait que "hôte" peut désigner soit la personne qui reçoit, soit les invités...

Comment: en résumé, on peut tout à fait le dire à des hôtes uniquement quand "hôtes" a le sens "invités", mais la formule reste très formelle.

Comment: Parce qu'il y a déjà 3 réponses allant globallement dans le même sens, la mienne serait redondante et que je ne réponds qu'à 1 point sur les 3 de ta question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tout d'abord, en France, seule la personne qui reçoit souhaite la bienvenue à ses invités.

Aussi, en français, il y a un ambigüité sur le mot "hôte", qui peut autant signifier la personne qui reçoit (l'hôte), que les personnes reçues (les hôtes)

**1.**
En disant :

> Bienvenue à nos hôtes

Il y a une *certaine* distance (nuancée par l'intonation), car vous ne vous adressez pas directement aux invités. Cela implique que vous parlez à un grand groupe de personne, et que seulement une partie est nouvelle venue. Vous parlez donc au groupe entier avec cette formulation.
On pourrait dire similairement :

> Je tiens à souhaiter la bienvenue à nos hôtes

Qui est plus personnelle par l'ajout de la première personne.
Cela implique donc que vous êtes heureux de recevoir ces personnes (vous indiquez qu'ils ont été invités et qu'ils sont au bon endroit), et que vous espérez qu'ils se sentirons bien chez vous (ou dans l'endroit où vous êtes).
Cela marque le début de l'accueil, c'est en général une des premières phrases que l'on dit, quand les hôtes découvrent le lieu, en indiquant donc que vous allez tout faire pour vous occuper d'eux.

**2.** En utilisant **mes**, cela rajoute de la proximité (de la chaleur humaine) avec les hôtes, mais la formulation est toujours distante (avec nuance...) car vous parlez toujours à un groupe entier, dont une partie est nouvelle venue.

**3.** Les gens répondent en général tout simplement

> Merci !

**Remarque 1**: La distance créée avec ces formulations peut être volontaire, cela peut signaler une distance "professionnelle" avec les hôtes, que vous ne connaissez pas personnellement.

**Remarque 2**: Pour supprimer cette distance, si vous le souhaitez, vous pouvez tous simplement dire

> Je vous souhaite la bienvenue

qui est plus personnel.
Vous pouvez aussi dire, si vous vous adressez à un grand nombre de personnes (disons à partir de 10 ?) :

> Bienvenue à tous

**Remarque 3**: Dans votre cas, quand vous êtes invité, il n'y a pas de formulation du genre, si ce n'est

> Merci pour l'invitation

ou

> Ravi(e) d'être présent(e)

Mais c'est très majoritairement à la personne qui reçoit de commencer les formules de politesses.

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord avec toi sur la distance de cette formulation. C'est surtout le ton avec laquelle elle sera dite qui donnera de la chaleur ou non.

Comment: @YohannV. Personnellement, je perçoit une distance car il n'y a ni la 2ème (tu) ni la 5ème (vous) personne. Ce qui implique qu'on ne s'adresse pas directement aux invités, ce qui implique une distance avec eux. Alors que **Je vous souhaite la bienvenue** s'adresse directement aux invités. Après, il est vrai qu'on peut rajouter de la chaleur avec l’intonation, mais avec la même intonation, je trouve la formulation plus distante qu'avec "**vous**"

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec toi sur la forme, mais elle est tellement employé que sa forme n'a plus autant d'importance. Comme l'emploi de cette formule se fait principalement dans le cadre d'accueil d'un locataire/client d'hôtel, elle est donc distante *dans sa forme* car l'accueilli s'attend à être reçu avec un certain standing, cependant avec le bon ton, elle peut être *très chaleureuse* et pas le moins du monde froide.

Comment: @YohannV. Ok... je rajoute une nuance... :)

Answer (score 5):

1 ) Il y a peut-être des variantes régionales, mais cette phrase sonnerait faux en Belgique et en France dans le contexte que vous présentez. En effet, c'est à la personne qui accueille de souhaiter la bienvenue, et non aux invités. Souhaiter la bienvenue à la personne qui invite n'a pas de sens.

Je pense que la confusion vient du mot "hôte" qui peut signifier soit la personne qui accueille, soit la personne qui est accueillie (avec "louer", c'est un des pires cas de polysémie).

2) La personne qui accueille utilisera "Bienvenue à mes hôtes!" si elle est seule et qu'elle ne veut pas se montrer trop distante.

3) Si mes invités me souhaitaient la bienvenue, je ne saurais pas quoi répondre... Dans l'autre sens (si la personne qui m'accueille me souhaite la bienvenue), "merci" me viendrait naturellement à l'esprit (ou bien "nous sommes honorés de votre hospitalité" pour rester dans le formel).

Comment: @Divulgâchâmes "dans l'autre sens" veut ici dire "en retour", donc quand la personne qui reçoit vous souhaite la bienvenue, vous pouvez répondre "nous sommes honorés de votre hospitalité" (qui est formel)

Answer (score 4):

#### 1.

Cela n'est pas approprié à la situation car on ne souhaite pas la bienvenue à ceux qui nous permettent de résider chez eux.

On souhaite comme tu l'as cité *"l'arrivée propice"* ou *"l'accueil aimable"*. Ce ne sont pas les personnes qui arrivent et qui sont hébergées qui vont le souhaiter à celles qui accueillent mais bien le contraire.

Si tu veux dire que tu as été bien accueilli, tu peux simplement dire :

> Quel {super{be}} accueil !

#### 2.

Si tu loues une chambre d'hôtel et que les propriétaires doivent te rendre visite, tu peux effectivement dire

> Bienvenue à mes hôtes !

Cela rendra la formule *légèrement* plus chaleureuse que

> Bienvenue à nos hôtes !

Qui l'est déjà, de par la formule.

#### 3.

La réponse la plus simple est de remercier l'autre de nous accueillir avec autant de chaleur.

> Merci beaucoup !

Comment: @Divulgâchâmes Non, si tu es seul, il faudra utiliser *"mes"*. (Tu veux demander *Qu'est-ce qui ...* j'imagine). La formule est chaleureuse car accueillante et bienveillante. Même si elle témoigne d'un certain respect, à mon sens, son utilisation est devenue courante et ne représente plus un langage aussi soutenu.

Comment: @Divulgâchâmes Comme j'en ai discuté avec Random, le contexte et le ton indiquent plus comment il faut prendre la formule. Reste que dans un contexte courant, on ne souhaite pas la bienvenue à ceux qui nous accueillent. Quelles sont les points qui restent encore inexpliqués pour toi, après ces trois réponses?