# "sont les bienvenue" : est-ce correct ? Pourquoi "les" ?

Tags: expressions, usage, étymologie, accord

Dans une fiche de poste j'ai lu :

> Toutes les thématiques de l'analyse numérique, calcul scientifique et modélisation sont les bienvenue. Les candidatures permettant de développer des interactions interdisciplinaires ou des applications biomédicales seront appréciées.

La tournure *sont les bienvenue* est-elle correcte ? Pourquoi bienvenue et non bienvenue**S** ? Je crois que c'est une coquille mais il me faut le vérifier.

De plus, quel est le rôle de **les** dans cette tournure ? Pourquoi pas *sont bienvenues* tout simplement ?

Ce [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sont%20bienvenus%2Csont%20les%20bienvenus&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csont%20bienvenus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csont%20les%20bienvenus%3B%2Cc0) montre clairement que la première tournure est tout à fait la tournure usuelle depuis bien longtemps. Cependant je cherche à comprendre pourquoi l'article est nécessaire ici.

Autres exemples :

> - Soyez **la** bienvenue dans notre équipe.
> - Michel est **le** bienvenu dans notre maison n’importe quand.
> - Les parents et les amis seront **les** bienvenus lors de la cérémonie.

Comment: [This answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7643/%C3%AAtre-bienvenu-et-%C3%AAtre-le-bienvenu/7644#7644) seems to address the "article vs zero article" part of your question (perhaps better stated as the "noun vs adjective" part of it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il manque bien sûr un *s* à *bienvenues*, mais il me semble qu'il faudrait aussi ajouter des articles à la première phrase:

> Toutes les thématiques de l'analyse numérique, **du** calcul scientifique et **de la** modélisation sont les bienvenue**s**.

Pour ce qui est de la présence d'un article défini, ***bienvenue*** n'est pas vraiment un substantif ici. Le vrai substantif *bienvenue* est essentiellement utilisé pour désigner l'accueil lui-même plutôt que la personne accueillie.

Je n'ai jamais entendu dire ***<s>je vous présente la bienvenue</s>*** ou ***<s>voici les bienvenus</s>***, pas plus que ***<s>c'est une bienvenue</s>***. Au mieux peut-on entendre ***Ce n'est pas un bienvenu ici*** en concurrence avec ***Il n'est pas le bienvenu ici***.

On devrait donc considérer que *bienvenue* garde sa valeur d'adjectif et remarquer qu'il a au moins un point commun avec ce que Gabriel Wyler appelle un *[adjectif sélecteur](http://gabrielwyler.com/page017.html)* comme le sont *seul*, *premier*, *suivant* ou *principal*, celui de requérir l'article défini.

On dit bien:

> Soyez le seul
> Soyez le premier
> Soyez le suivant
> Soyez le principal

et pas

> <s>Soyez un seul</s>
> <s>Soyez un premier</s>
> <s>Soyez un suivant</s>
> <s>Soyez un principal</s>

donc

> **...sont les bienvenues**
>
> **Soyez le bienvenu**

et pas

> **...<s>sont des bienvenues</s>**
>
> **Soyez un bienvenu**

Comme il s'agit d'un adjectif, l'absence d'article est aussi possible mais semble parfois moins naturelle :

> Toutes les thématiques sont bienvenues.
>
> Soyez bienvenue dans notre équipe.
>
> Michel est bienvenu dans notre maison n’importe quand.
>
> Les parents et les amis seront bienvenus lors de la cérémonie.

Answer (score 2):

Dans le présent cas il faut écrire « bienvenues ».

[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sont+les+bienvenus%2Csont+les+bienvenue&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csont%20les%20bienvenus%3B%2Cc0) ; il s'agit du substantif [(TLFi)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bienvenu).

- La directrice est la bienvenue à la réception.
- Le chat n'est pas le bienvenu dans la cuisine.
- Les infirmières sont les bienvenues à la réunion.

Il s'agit simplement de deux substantifs : « bienvenu » et  « bienvenue » ; ils ont donc un pluriel et l'article doit être celui qui convient pour le pluriel.

Le TLFi considère les formes suivantes comme des syntagmes figés;

> B. Subst. Personne bienvenue; **être le bienvenu chez qqn**;
>  
>   Formule d'accueil. **Soyez le (la) bienvenu(e)**

Comment: Merci. Cependant pourquoi **sont les bienvenues** et non sont bienvenues tout simplement ? Quel est le rôle de ce les ici ?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sont+bienvenus%2Csont+les+bienvenus&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csont%20bienvenus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csont%20les%20bienvenus%3B%2Cc0 Le Ngram montre que la première tournure est tout à fait la bonne tournure. Cependant je cherche à comprendre pourquoi l'article est nécessaire ici.

Comment: @Dimitris Bonne question ! Je ne vois pas très bien, c'est peut être un idiomatisme ; il faut que je regarde de plus près.

Comment: @Dimitris L'article est justifié par l'auteur parce quil est libre de choisir  soit l'un soit l'autre de l'adjectif et du substantif. Plus énigmatique est cette utilisation d'un article défini, je ne saisi pas cela d'emblée. On comprendrais « un bienvenu » mais ça ne se dit pas.

Comment: Pourquoi trouver énigmatique l'article défini ? On s'adresse à une personne en particulier, celle qui est **la** bienvenue. On peut de même aussi dire *soyez **le** meilleur*, *soyez **les** plus sages*, etc. Dire *soyez un meilleur*, *soyez un bienvenu*, *soyez des plus sages* ne se dit pas et n'aurait de toute façon pas le même sens. Voir la différence entre « *sois **un** homme !*  » et « *sois **l**'homme !*  ».

Comment: @jlliagre Deux personnes, deux dames, se présentent à un rassemblement quelconque ; la première est accueillie par un « Soyez la bienvenue ! » puis la seconde aussi ; lorsqu'elles se parlent l'une dit « Je suis la première arrivée, on m'a dit à l'entrèe que j'étais la bienvenue. »; la seconde lui répond « Oui vous êtes la première, mais la bienvenue c'est moi ! ». Qu'est-ce que vous lui dites à cette dame (la seconde) ?

Comment: Qu'elle aussi est **la** bienvenue et donc que toutes deux sont **les** bienvenues. Au moment de l'accueil, si une seule personne se présente, elle est à ce moment là **la** bienvenue mais si plusieurs personnes se présentent, ce sont **les** bienvenus. Être le bienvenu n'est pas exclusif mais fait entrer dans le groupe des personnes bienvenues. Employé avec l'article indéfini, ***une** bienvenue* signifie surtout l'accueil lui-même, et ***un** bienvenu* est rare.

Comment: @jlliagre Bien d'accord avec ça, mais il y a deux emplois de l'article  sans aucune équivoque, ce qui intéresse le linguiste, le grammairien; le premier emploi est **déterminatif**, pas générique; donc si dans le second cas il n'est pas déterminatif quel est cet emploi ou plutôt ne s'agirait-il pas d'un idiomatisme ? Notons que la logique veut l'article indéfini.

Comment: Je comprends l'argument. Peut-être faudrait-il alors considérer ici *bienvenu* non pas comme un substantif mais d'une certaine manière, encore comme un adjectif. Plus précisément un adjectif proche de ce que Gabriel Wyler appelle un *adjectif sélecteur*. On dira *soyez le suivant* et pas *soyez un suivant*.

Comment: @jlliagre Je ne sais pas, mais cette question n'est pas nouvelle, elle reste sans réponse et laisse tout le monde dans le vague (voir [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/7644/17649))